# Reverse Zoom of Action Pen Excel 365

Tags: excel, vba, excel-365

I am trying to undo the Action Pen zoom in Excel 365. As soon as the element is selected, it goes to 400%.

The following Code is working

```
Sub LockZoom()

Do
 If ActiveWindow.Zoom <> 100 Then
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
 End If
 DoEvents
Loop While True

End Sub
```

But how to run it?
I tried to autostart the Code, but Excel seems to freez due to the do loop.
I tried to run the code (without do loop) if I make a change (select a cell). However, with the selection from the action pen, I don´t make a change.
I have tried to determine the event of the selection of the Action Pen, but the marco recoder  can´t record it and I haven´t found how to do it.

Does anyone have any ideas or solutions?

Comment: It freezes because you never leave the loop. Why do you use a loop at all?

Comment: I believe the OP wants this to be running constantly, as they're not aware of an event that could be utilised.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't expect that anyone would want to forbid a user to zoom. Not all eyes are the same, and not all monitors either...

Comment: Yes, I used the loop because I am not aware of an event I can utilise in this case.
The application is an fixed "Whiteboard" on a fixed monitor, so yes, i want to forbid the zoom.